# MoveRow method not animating when moving between sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Im creating Shopping List app. I use 2 sections for separating bought items and Items that are not bought. I use moveRow method for moving rows between said 2 sections. This is the code for moving rows.

```
if indexPath.section == 0 {
    self.shoppingItems.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    self.shoppingItemsBought.append(item)
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()

    let fromIndexPath = NSIndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section: 0)
    let toIndexPath = NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 1)

    self.tableView.moveRow(at: fromIndexPath as IndexPath, to: toIndexPath as IndexPath)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()

} else {
    self.shoppingItemsBought.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    self.shoppingItems.append(item)
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()

    let fromIndexPath = NSIndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section: 1)
    let toIndexPath = NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)

    self.tableView.moveRow(at: fromIndexPath as IndexPath, to: toIndexPath as IndexPath)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
 }
```

The rows change their location but without animation.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `CATransaction` around the `moveRow`. Put your changes inside the CATransaction block and on completion, force the reload. This will do the reload with animations.

Example:

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
    tableView.reloadData()
}

tableView.beginUpdates()

// Update the datasource
if indexPath.section == 0 {
    self.shoppingItems.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    self.shoppingItemsBought.append(item)
}
else {
    self.shoppingItemsBought.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    self.shoppingItems.append(item)
}

// Get new IndexPath (indexPath is the old one, as in current)
let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: indexPath.section == 0 ? 1 : 0)

// Move the row in tableview
tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath, to: newIndexPath)

tableView.endUpdates()
CATransaction.commit()
```